# Populate column with a default value

Tags: mysql

I'm working in MYSQL 2008 and I have created a simple table:

```
create table Productos (
nombre char (30),
size int,
nota char (40))
```

I need to create a trigger for insert. When I insert values I only need to provide values for `nombre`, `size` and `nota` needs to be `NULL`.

The trigger needs to populate `nota` if `size` from inserted is `> 50`, it needs to populate the column with the word `mayor` and if it is `< 50` with the word `menor`.

This is what I have tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Inserta
ON Productos
for INSERT
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(
            SELECT NULL
            FROM Productos
          )
            Begin
  UPDATE Productos
    SET nota = 
        CASE 
            WHEN (select size
   from inserted ) > 50 
                THEN 'Mayor'
   Else 'Menor'
        END
    from 
    inserted
    End
    End
```

This is changing the values of all the columns, not just the inserted ones. I'm a newbie on this and I am confused.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Did you mean SQL Server 2008 or MySQL on windows 2008 ?

Comment: Just change column definition and make it DEFAULT NULL

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER Inserta BEFORE INSERT on Productos
SET nota = CASE WHEN new.size > 50 THEN 'Mayor' Else 'Menor' END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I tried CREATE TRIGGER Inserta BEFORE INSERT on Productos
SET nota = CASE WHEN new.size > 50 THEN 'Mayor' Else 'Menor' END; but it is giving me an error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Inserta, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'BEFORE'. @Joe Frambach

Comment: Sorry, I meant MySQL on windows 8. @Prix

Comment: What do I need to do for it to update only the inserted values, not the whole table?